# Two channel logical switch

Tags: switches, logic-gates, switching, boolean-algebra

I'm trying to make a theoretical automated battery charger using a reactor only with logical gates, and I wanted to use charge cycles between 30 and 80% for efficiency sake. I can output a 0 or a 1 whenever the battery gets either below 30% or above 80%, and I have a simple input that turns the charger on and off.

My idea was to make a switch that turns on when battery goes below 30% (first line inputs a 1) and turns off ONLY when the battery is above 80% (second line now inputs a 1 while the first one stopped doing so a while ago), but the problem is that I don't know how this switch is called and if it can be made with logical gates only.

Comment: Be careful. Have you considered that as soon as you start to charge that the voltage may rise over 80% and you'll have created an oscillator?

Comment: Your circuit needs *memory* to remember that the 30% signal turned high a while ago. Look into SR latches which can be *set* (30% signal) and *reset* (80% signal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into the function of an [SR latch](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/digital/chpt-10/s-r-latch/).

> In an S-R latch, activation of the S input sets the circuit, while activation of the R input resets the circuit.

In your case the <30% signal can be connected to the set and >80% signal can be connected to the reset inputs. Fortunately, both the above won't be high at the same time.

SR latch can be made using gates (and feedback connections)